# Rambling-slider-rails shows only blank screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm making an app using Rails 4.0.1 with Ruby 2.0 and I'm running into trouble installing the "Rambling slider" image carousel from [here](https://github.com/gonzedge/rambling-slider-rails).

Here's the portion of the gemfile:

```
...
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'rambling-slider-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/gonzedge/rambling-slider-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
...
```

I ran `bundle install` and, following the instructions, put a reference to jquery.rambling.slider in my manifest files.

My `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.rambling.slider
//= require_tree .
```

My `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file:

```
/*
*= require jquery.rambling.slider
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

I included the link tags in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` like so:

```
...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery.rambling.slider' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.rambling.slider' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
...
```

Then added some dummy images and the invoking javascript in the actual view accordingly:

```
<div id="slider">
  <%= image_tag "lorem1.jpeg" %>
  <%= image_tag "lorem2.jpeg" %>
  <%= image_tag "lorem3.jpeg" %>
</div>

<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#slider').ramblingSlider();
  });
</script>
```

But all that appears a simple 1'2'3 on the page.

I know that the images are referenced correctly because when I comment out the script in the view file, the 3 images appear with no problems.

The developer tools in Chrome only show that there is a single warning saying "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." at jquery.js?body=1:5375. (I can show this line too if you need it)  This warning only appears when the script is uncommented.  As soon as I comment it out, the warning goes away.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not need any of the javascript_include_tag or stylesheet_include_tag s. Remove them. The event.returnValue has nothing to do with your slider. Ignore that warning.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you mentioned(1,2,3 links) occurs because the theme effect was not included, You can include this by adding a div with "theme-default" class, present in the .css file of rambling-slider. For this to work you also need to add the **themes** folder in **stylesheet** & **images** folder of your application

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
  <div id="slider" class="ramblingSlider">
   <%= image_tag "lorem1.jpeg" %>
   <%= image_tag "lorem2.jpeg" %>
   <%= image_tag "lorem3.jpeg" %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```